# What is a word or phrase that describes two ideas that historically were at odds now being in harmony with one another?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on a project related to innovation in manufacturing. I'm trying to find a word or phrase that describes two ideas that used to be considered in conflict with one another now being in harmony because of innovation and technological advancements.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a single word, and I'm not yet sure how it would be used in a sentence. I'm working on branding for a project. I'm trying to brainstorm language that communicates two ideas that historically were in conflict with each other, now because of innovation, being in harmony. 

I've been at a creative roadblock, so I thought I would reach out here to see if anyone could help!

Comment: The (leading) CED definition of _harmonisation_ would seem to me to work well.

Comment: *Reunite or reunify?*

Comment: An example of the situation you have in mind would be helpful

Comment: integration of two disparate ideas became possible with technological advances.

Answer (score 2):

If two things are in opposition but come into agreement, they [**reconcile**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reconcile):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : to restore to friendship or harmony
>   // *reconciled* the factions
>   **1 b** : SETTLE, RESOLVE
>   // *reconcile* differences
>   **2** : to make consistent or congruous
>   // *reconcile* an ideal with reality

For example:

> The married couple who had found themselves in opposition over the buying a car with either automatic or manual transmission *reconciled* when they found a car with dual-mode transmission that allowed them to switch between the two as they desired.

Using the word in the case of the scenario in the question would rely on more context. However, a rough attempt at such a sentence without any more detail could be something like this:

> The previously opposed ideas were *reconciled* through an innovation that allowed them to coexist without conflict.

---

A different word, that puts more focus on the innovation itself, is [**unify**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unify).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/coalesce

**coalesce**

verb (used without object), co·a·lesced, co·a·lesc·ing.

--to grow together or into one body:

The two lakes coalesced into one.

--to unite so as to form one mass, community, etc.:

The various groups coalesced into a crowd.

--to blend or come together:

Their ideas coalesced into one theory.

verb (used with object), co·a·lesced, co·a·lesc·ing.

--to cause to unite in one body or mass.

Answer (score 0):

The following might work well in the context of manufacturing. From M-W:

> **[integration](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integration)**: the act or process or an instance of integrating
>
> **[integrate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integrate)**: to form, coordinate, or blend into a functioning or unified whole

Examples: **Integration** of systems or processes that previously worked at cross purposes.